# Type 'TestComponent' has no properties in common with type 'CmsComponent'

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I have a set of custom components which is created in CMS. The custom components extend the BannerComponent and have it's own property called "color".

I have created the model:

```
    import { BannerComponent } from '@spartacus/storefront';


    export class TestComponent extends BannerComponent{
        color?: string;
    }
```

And I am trying to get the data from the Angular component.

constructor(private componentData: CmsComponentData,
private cmsService: CmsService) { }

While doing this I am getting the following error:

Type 'TestComponent' has no properties in common with type 'CmsComponent'.

How to resolve this and get data of custom component in the angular component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting is coming from the typescript compiler. During that check, there's no information available to understand that you're actually expecting a `BannerComponent` interface. Remember, typescript is doing static code validation.

To make the compiler aware of the expected interface, you need to tell it. By default, the `CmsComponentData` class uses the `CmsComponent` interface. You can however pass in a custom interface, by passing the interface to the `CmsComponentData`:

```js
export interface TestComponent extends CmsBannerComponent{
  color?: string;
}

constructor(
  private componentData: CmsComponentData<TestComponent>, 
  private cmsService: CmsService
) { }
```

Comment: constructor(private componentData: CmsComponentData<TestComponent>, 
    private cmsService: CmsService) { }

I tried the same and I am getting the same error. (Type 'TestComponent' has no properties in common with type 'CmsComponent'.)

Comment: my bad, you actually need to make it an interface rather than a type. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I gave the interface instead of class and checked now. Again it is showing the same error. Am I missing something anywhere?

Comment: Do I need to import/declare my TestComponent anywhere in angular?

Comment: Thanks for the example, i've fixed the error in my example above. Instead of extending from `BannerComponent`, you must extend from `CmsBannerComponent`. `BannerComponent` is a component class, where as `CmsBannerComponent` is an interface.

Comment: Thank you. I have changed that now I am facing another issue. NullInjectorError: No provider for CmsComponentData!. I tried to add CmsComponentData in the providers but it is showing "Type 'type of CmsComponentData' is not assignable to type 'Provider'". Can you advise me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Model Class:

```
    import { BannerComponent } from '@spartacus/storefront';
    export interface TestComponent extends BannerComponent{
        color?: string;
    }
```

Component:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { CmsService } from '@spartacus/core';
    import {  CmsComponentData } from '@spartacus/storefront';
    import { TestComponent } from 'src/app/models/service-tile.model';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-service-tile',
      templateUrl: './service-tile.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./service-tile.component.scss']
    })
    export class ServiceTileComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(private componentData: CmsComponentData<TestComponent>, 
        private cmsService: CmsService) { }
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }

    }
```

Response from hybris:

```
    {
     "slotId" : "Section1",
     "slotUuid" : "yyyy",
     "position" : "ServiceTileSection",
     "name" : "Service Tile Section",
     "slotShared" : false,
     "components" : {
        "component" : [ {
            "uid" : "TestComponent",
            "uuid" : "xxxx",
           "typeCode" : "ServiceTileBannerComponent",
           "modifiedtime" : "2020-10-07T21:18:28.4+05:30",
           "name" : "Component",
           "container" : "false",
           "external" : "false",
           "color" : "RED",
           "media" : {
              "code" : "Tile1.jpg",
              "mime" : "image/png",
              "altText" : "Car Trade In",
              "url" : "/medias/?context=3NGMyZjRkZTU4YTMz"
           },
           "headline" : "Test"
        },
        {
            component2
        },
        {
            component3
        }
    ]
    }
    }
```

This is the exact classes that I am using in my sample.